# What's the difference between "loses" and "lost" in "…whoever loses/lost will do five push-ups"?

Tags: tense

(1) Healthy gamble, whoever loses will do five push-ups.

(2) Healthy gamble, whoever lost will do five push-ups.

Which one sounds better? For the second one, is that how a mixture of past tense and future tense should work?

Comment: I can just about make out what you mean by "healthy gamble", but it's not idiomatic, We use the past (historically a "past subjunctive") for _irrealis_ (or counter-factual) conditions. Here the condition (losing) is still to come, and so is not counter-factual, and the present _loses_ would be better.

Comment: @Col Irrealis modality: references an event not currently true, real, observable. *I recommend he be punished.* Counter-factual involves a conditional that can no longer come true. *Had I known, I'd have quit.* https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-dictionary-of-linguistics/020FAAA378FE9F40D98488118A0C2187/listing?q=IRREALIS&fts=yes&searchWithinIds=020FAAA378FE9F40D98488118A0C2187&aggs%5BproductTypes%5D%5Bfilters%5D=BOOK_PART

Comment: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-dictionary-of-linguistics/020FAAA378FE9F40D98488118A0C2187/listing?q=COUNTERFACTUAL&searchWithinIds=020FAAA378FE9F40D98488118A0C2187&fts=yes&searchWithinIds=020FAAA378FE9F40D98488118A0C2187&aggs%5BproductTypes%5D%5Bfilters%5D=BOOK_PART

Comment: OK. I've always understood _irrealis_ to mean the same as _counterfactual_, but I see there can be a distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Both OP's examples are syntactically valid, but the second ("past in the future") construction is relatively unlikely. I'd normally expect a context-specific justification for shifting the "temporal focus" forward as in example #2. For example,...

> 3: *Zuckerberg and Musk are having a cage fight tomorrow. **Next week,** whoever **lost** will sign over his entire company to the winner*

In my example, "next week" encourages the reader to interpret following text as being based in the future - *after* the cage fight (so it can be referenced using past tense). But it would be easier to just ignore that possibility and stick with constructions like...

> 4: *Zuckerberg and Musk are having a cage fight tomorrow. Whoever **loses** will sign over his entire company to the winner **next week***

...where because "next week" doesn't appear until the *end* of the clause it modifies, the reader won't expect a reference to the *outcome* of the cage fight to be set in the past.

Comment: I believe the technically correct phrasing for the first example would be, "Next week, whoever **will have lost** will sign over his entire company to the winner."  The logically correct tense for an action completed in the future would be future perfect, but actually using it would make the sentence *sound* very awkward.

Comment: Not a chance! No native speaker would ever use ***whoever will have lost*** in contexts like this - I can only assume that's some kind of "word-for-word" translation from your own native language. See [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whoever+will+have+lost+will%2Cwhoever+loses+will+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: The future perfect version wasn't a translation, it was a hypothetical construction. Also https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whoever+will+have+lost+will%2Cwhoever+lost+will&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 so it looks like the only 'acceptable' version is the present tense

Comment: All 3 on the same plot: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whoever+will+have+lost+will%2Cwhoever+lost+will%2Cwhoever+loses+will&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3